# How to convert content between two patterns into specific format using shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed, gawk

How do we convert the content between 2 patterns into specific format using shell code? The following sample XML that starts with `<Mapping>` and ends with `</Mapping>` needs to be converted to plan format code as shown below.

Sample input code:

```
 <Mapping name="temp1">   /*rule name will the value of Mapping name*/
               <phpCode>
                   boolean_out = copyfunc temp  /*rule content output */
               </phpCode>
 </Mapping>
```

The value of `name` will be the rule name and the value of `boolean_out` will be rule content.

Sample output code:

```
rule temp1 { // temp1 is the mapping value
  copyfunc temp //boolean_out  value is rule content
}
```

Comment: Use XSLT or [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or another xml processing tool.

Answer (score 2):

Given input.xml containing:

```
<Mapping name="temp1">   /*rule name will the value of Mapping name*/
              <phpCode>
                   boolean_out = copyfunc temp  /*rule content output */
              </phpCode>
</Mapping>
```

And transform.xsl containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="Mapping">
  <xsl:text>rule </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
  <xsl:text> { // </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
  <xsl:text> is the mapping value</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./phpCode" mode="php-code" />
  <xsl:text>&#x0a;}&#x0a;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="php-code">
  <xsl:text>&#x0a;  </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(text()),'= '),'/*')" />
  <xsl:text>//</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(normalize-space(text()),'=')" />
  <xsl:text> value is rule content</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An XSLT transform produces:

```
rule temp1 { // temp1 is the mapping value
  copyfunc temp //boolean_out  value is rule content
}
```

The method of invoking the transform is platform and tool-specific.  Command line tools can be used to invoke a transformation, though there are any number of ways to run the XSL script.  For example, an `xsltproc` command is:

```
xsltproc transform.xsl input.xml
```

One can use `msxsl.exe` similarly, except that the command arguments are reversed.